# Removing a validation at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Below I can successfully add a validation at runtime to Mongoid:

```
class Abc
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :something, type: String
end

 a = Abc.new
a.valid?
 => true 

Abc.class_eval do
  validates_presence_of :something
end
 => [Mongoid::Validatable::PresenceValidator] 
 b = Abc.new
=> #<Abc _id: 55948e466d616344a4010000, something: nil> 
b.valid?
 => false
```

How do you remove a validation? If possible, I assume it would be the same for both ActiveRecord and Mongoid.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
Abc.class_eval do
  remove_validates_presence_of :something
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find what you want in this blog post: http://gistflow.com/posts/749-canceling-validations-in-activerecord

Basically, the validators information are in the class variable `_validators`, and you can call `skip_callback` to cancel it.
So you should be able to remove it with

```
validators = Abc._validators[:something] 
v = validators.first
validators.delete v
filter = Abc._validate_callbacks.find { |c| c.raw_filter == v }.filter
skip_callback :validate, filter
```